# jQuery dialog won't open when loading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I am new to javascript and am trying to make a simple dialog open when the page opens, but it simply just displays the

text of the dialog as if its a normal paragraph, no dialog. Here's my index.html:

```
<html xmlns=\ "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xml:lang=\"en\">
<head>
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Script-Type" CONTENT="text/javascript">
  <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js'></script>
  <title>Welcome to Jetty-9</title>
  <style type="text/css" title="maincss">
    @import url(maincss.css);
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $("#dialog").dialog();
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And my maincss.css simply puts a background image in for the body nothing else, and the js/jquery.js file is the latest version of jquery, and I ensured it is linked right by loading the page, viewing page source, then opening the js file by clicking it

Comment: `Dialog` is part of jquery UI, are you including that in your HTML?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include jQuery UI to take advantage of the dialog.

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

you have to import the JQuery UI's api's AFTER the JQuery main file

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

This way is should work:

```
<html xmlns=\ "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xml:lang=\"en\">
<head>
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Script-Type" CONTENT="text/javascript">
  <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js'></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <title>Welcome to Jetty-9</title>
  <style type="text/css" title="maincss">
    @import url(maincss.css);
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $("#dialog").dialog();
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're trying to use [jquery-ui dialog](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/), if this is the case, you need to include [jquery-ui](http://jqueryui.com/) files

These are latest versions from CDN

```
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css
```

You could pick a different theme if required

Answer (score 0):

You are missing jQuery UI. Include the below code in `head` of your page.

```
<link href='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
```

Visit **[here](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2013/05/jquery-ui-1-10-3/)** for more CDN links of various versions of jquery ui & its themes.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good and it is working. My guess is you're not properly importing the `jQuery` or `jQuery UI`.

Updated with reference to  **MaVRoSCy** comments and take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hUb8S/2/), working good.

Comment: About your last comment, about the document.ready(), what OP is doing and what you are proposing is essentially the same. Check it out http://jsfiddle.net/hUb8S/1/

Comment: @MaVRoSCy Oh I was wrong. May I know the difference between them?

Comment: no difference at all. Check http://api.jquery.com/ready/ `The .ready() method is typically used with an anonymous function:$(document).ready(function() {
// Handler for .ready() called.
}); Which is equivalent to calling: $(function() {
// Handler for .ready() called.
});`